# Apache map URL to resource

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I'm hoping someone can help me out with my configs for apache. I have all my mod_proxy config working, but I want to add to the config so I can map /fog to serve up /var/www/fog/index.php but I'm unsure how to do this as I've only ever used apache for proxy pass.

This is my mod_proxy.conf so far:

```
<VirtualHost *>
<Location /movies>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8082/movies
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8082/movies
</Location>

<Location /tv>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/tv
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8081/tv
</Location>

<Location /download>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/sabnzbd
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/sabnzbd
</Location>

<Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8083/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8083/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also tried adding the following to the top of mod_proxy.conf:

```
Alias /fog /var/www/fog/management
```

But I just get a blank page when I hit /fog

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out so I'll post to help others

```
ProxyPass /fog !

Alias /fog /var/www/fog
```

Using the ! directive prevents the proxy of /fog using the ProxyPass rule and allows the Alias to be used, without this the Alias is ignored.